# STUFF function along with charIndex() in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stuff

I need to display a table column (assume 2 columns) values with comma-separated in the output

Table t1:

```
col1    Col2    
================
xyz       ab/cde 
pqr       uv/wxy 
xyz       fg/hij     
lmn       rtg
pqr       12/456
```

Table t2:

```
col1        
======
xyz         
pqr
```

Output needed:(column col2 to be populated in table2 with following values)

```
col1    Col2    
================
xyz     ab,fg
pqr     uv,12
```

Output expected :

- col1 values of t1 should be equal to col1 values of t2.
- For the records passing step1, take col2 values before slash from t1 and have them comma separated for each value of col1.
- **EDITED :**

How to get only distinct values from col2 of t1 table. Ex: if the values of the table are

```
col1    Col2    
================
xyz       ab/cde 
pqr       uv/wxy 
xyz       fg/hij     
lmn       fg
pqr       fg/456 tehn output to be only ab,fg,uv...
```

Can anyone please help me on this?I'm not getting on how to do it in sql server.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And does order matter or would `fg,ab` also be acceptable? If order matters, how do we determine order? Is there another column perhaps?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: It seems you want `LEFT` not `STUFF` to get the first characters. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Also what happens if you have an additional row with a value in `col2` that doesn't have a slash, e.g. `xyz, rtg`? Does `,rtg` get added to the string, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a version that supports `STRING_AGG`:

```
UPDATE t2 
  SET t2.col2 = agg.agg
FROM dbo.t2
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT col1,
    agg = STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(col2, 1, 
          NULLIF(charindex('/', col2)-1,-1)), ',')
  FROM dbo.t1
  GROUP BY col1
) AS agg
ON t2.col1 = agg.col1;
```

If you want the resulting string to contain values from `t2.col2` that *don't* contain slashes (ambiguous given the sample data), change the `NULLIF` line to:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(charindex('/', col2)-1,-1), 255)), ',')
```

- [Examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wp_i22fp)

And yes, if you want to code golf me, you could change...

```
SUBSTRING(col2, 1,
```

...to...

```
LEFT(col2,
```

##### Edited Answer:

To prevent duplicates, you have to use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` on the substring. I avoid duplicating the `LEFT`/`SUBSTRING` logic by using a CTE. There are certainly other ways (like `CROSS APPLY` perhaps).

```
WITH src AS 
  (
    SELECT col1, pf = LEFT(col2, 
           NULLIF(charindex('/', col2)-1,-1))
    FROM dbo.t1
  ),
  agg AS 
  (
    SELECT col1, agg = STRING_AGG(pf, ',')
    FROM (SELECT col1, pf FROM src GROUP BY col1, pf) AS x
    GROUP BY col1
  )
  UPDATE t2 SET t2.col2 = agg.agg
    FROM dbo.t2
    INNER JOIN agg 
    ON t2.col1 = agg.col1;
```

- [Updated example](https://dbfiddle.uk/JgHP61Kb)

Comment: This code worked..Thank you!

Comment: Can you please check the EDITED part in question above?

Comment: @Padmaja Please don't come up with new requirements that change the answer three weeks later - we call these "[chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/1274780)." Next time, please ask a new question.